# Prisma engine unable to download

Tags: node.js, prisma

Prisma init not working

```
npx prisma init
```

The console is returning the log belo3

Downloading Prisma engines for Node-API for windows [            ] 0%Error: request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/8fde8fef4033376662cad983758335009d522acb/windows/query_engine.dll.node.gz.sha256 failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 13728

Comment: Works fine for me; it's either a networking glitch or something w/ your DNS lookups, although I'm not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing weird errors to run `npx prisma init` as well, "connect ETIMEDOUT" in my case.

After some research I realized it was more a network bug than anything in my computer or in Prisma side, so I turned my machine off and went out for a coffee. After a couple hours I tried again and the download simply worked.

I hope somehow it helps you